# How to display SQL query that ran in WC_Order_Query?

Tags: php, wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, query, debug

Using `WP_Query` you can do: `(new WP_Query($arguments))->request` to get the raw SQL code that was executed.

But how can you do this with WooCommerces `WC_Order_Query` or `wc_get_orders`?

Answer (score 2):

`WC_Order_Query` does not store a record of the SQL it generated, or the `WP_Query` that it used internally. So it's not possible to get the information you need from `WC_Order_Query` directly.

You could *try* using `$wpdb->last_query` immediately after using the class or function, but the last query more than likely isn't the one you're actually looking for:

```
global $wpdb;

$orders = wc_get_orders();

$query = $wpdb->last_query;
```

Your best bet is to use a tool like [Query Monitor](https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/), which will allow you to see all the SQL queries run during a page load. You could use this to inspect your query.